# Classes whose members pointing to each other

Tags: c++, class, pointers

There is a `Square` which points to four `Face`s. Also each `Face` points to two `Square`s. Since one of the classes is defined first, compiler will complain. So how can I solve this problem? The aim of using pointers is that if I make a change in a face I will not need to make any changes for squares. In that case, this will be done automatically.

```
class Square
{
    Face* faces[4];
};

class Face
{
    Square* squares[2]
};
```

Comment: you can forward declare the name of one class

Comment: `class Face;` at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just forward declare one class;

```
class Face;
class Square{
 Face* faces[4];
};

class Face{
 Square* squares[2]
};
```

**Note:**  by forward declaration, you can only use *pointer/reference* (as you are using now). But you can not use like `Face faces[4];` in `Square`. Because it is a *declaration*, not *definition*. To use an object, compiler must know the definition of the object.